# 2000W Amp with 600W Wiring kit

Tags: chrysler

So, as per my first question on here, I did get the system today/yesterday. The amp itself is 2000W, but I was told by a rep at Best Buy that the 600W Amp Wiring Kit should be fine for my system. Is this true or should I have gotten a 2000W/3000W wiring kit instead.

The amp: [2000 w bass inferno](https://www.sears.com/bass-inferno-bass-inferno-2000w-4-channel-amplifier/p-SPM8149216902)

Comment: I think it’s probably fine. The worst that can happen is you’ll blow the fuse that came with the wiring kit. If you keep blowing fuses take it back and demand the bigger kit.

Comment: Are you planning to run your amp at 2000 watts? Probably not... Besides, the worst that will happen is needing to purchase a new fuse, it it's fused. If it's not fused, I wouldn't buy it.

Answer (score -1):

If the 600W kit was fine for 2000W it would state that on the packet. I suggest you received bad advice.

If you read the answers to your other question, there were some calculations of the current necessary - go back over them and compare those values with the ratings for the kit you bought....

Think about it - if the 600W kit was fine for 2000W the Marketing would not miss that opportunity...

I suggest you go back and get the correct kit...

Comment: Naaaa, Marketing would sell a kit labeled 600W, and exactly the same kit labeled 2000W for twice the money....

Comment: @sweber "How do you know when a marketing person is lying?".... Their mouth is open...